# Determining allowable moves on a grid

Tags: javascript, grid

Can anyone suggest a suitable way of figuring out a pieces allowable moves on a grid similar to the one in the image below.

[image: grid layout]

Assuming piece1 is at position a1 and piece2 is at position c3, how can I figure out which grid squares are allowable moves if piece1 can move (say) 3 squares and piece2 can move 2?

I've spent way too long developing text based MUDS it seems, I simply can't get my brain to take the next step into how to visualise potential movement even in the most simple of situations.

If it matters, I'm trying to do this in javascript, but to be perfectly honest I think my failure here is a failure to conceptualise properly - not a failure in language comprehension.

**Update - I'm adding the first round of code written after the below responses were posted. I thought it might be useful to people in a similar situation as me to see the code**

It's sloppy and it only works for one item placed on the board so far, but at least the `check_allowable_moves()` function works for this initial run. For those of you wondering why the hell I'm creating those weird alphanumeric objects rather than just using numeric x axis and y axis - it's because an id in HTML can't start with a number. In fact pretending I *could* use numbers to start ids helped a great deal in making sense of the functionality and concepts described by the fantastic answers I got.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml;utf-8"/>

<title>Test page</title>
<style> 

    #chessboard { clear: both; border:solid 1px black; height: 656px; 
                  width:656px; /*width = 8*40 + 16 for border*/ }
    #chessboard .row { overflow: auto; clear: both; }
    #chessboard .row span { display: block; height: 80px; 
                            width: 80px; float: left; 
                            border:solid 1px black; }
    .allowable { background: blue; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.2.6");
    google.load("jqueryui", "1.5.3");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function() {
    var global = this;
    global.Map = function(container) {
        function render_board() {
        var max_rows = 8;
        var cols = new Array('a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h');
        var jqMap = $('<div />');
        jqMap.attr('id', 'chessboard');
        var x=0;
        for(x; x<max_rows; x++) {
            var jqRow = $('<span />');
            jqRow.addClass('row');
            var i=0;
            for(i; i<cols.length; i++) {
                var jqCol = $('<span />');
                jqCol.attr('id', cols[i]+(x+1));
                jqCol.addClass(cols[i]);
                jqRow.append(jqCol);
            }
          jqMap.append(jqRow);
        }
     $('#'+container).append(jqMap);
   }
   function add_piece(where, id) {
     var jqPiece = $('<div>MY PIECE'+id+'</div>');
     var jqWhere = $('#'+where);
     jqPiece.attr('id', 'piece-'+id);
     jqPiece.addClass('army');
     jqPiece.draggable({cursor: 'move',
                              grid:[82, 82],
                              containment: '#chessboard',
                              revert: 'invalid',
                              stop: function(ev, ui) {
                                //console.log(ev.target.id);
                              }
                            });
     jqWhere.append(jqPiece);
     check_allowable_moves(where);
    }
    function check_allowable_moves(location) {
     var x_axis = { 'a':1,'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6, 'g':7, 'h':8 };
     var x_axis_alpha = { 1:'a',2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d', 5:'e', 6:'f', 7:'g', 8:'h' };
     $('.allowable').droppable("destroy");
     $('.allowable').removeClass('allowable');
     //get the x,y values of the piece just placed
     var x = parseInt(x_axis[location[0]], 10);
     var y = parseInt(location[1], 10);
     var x_min = x-2;
     var y_min = y-2;
      for(x_min; x_min<=x+2; x_min++) {
        for(y_min; y_min<=y+2; y_min++) {
           var jqCell = $('#'+x_axis_alpha[x_min]+y_min)
           jqCell.addClass('allowable');
           jqCell.droppable({ accept: '.army',
              drop: function(ev, ui) {
                //console.log(ev, ui, $(this));
                //handle_drop(ev, ui, $(this));
                check_allowable_moves($(this).attr('id'));
              }
            });
        }
        y_min = parseFloat(y)-2;
      }
    }
    render_board();
    add_piece('d5', '2');
   }
 })();
var map = new Map('content');
});
</script>
</head>

<body id="debug">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="content"> </div>
    </div><!-- end page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The image didn't make it into your post.

Comment: Image is there, just not displaying. Here's the URL: http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3534/3250436085_c91b07c7fd.jpg?v=0

Comment: Fixed, for some reason the markdown preview accepts urls with ?, but not the actual rendered post. Will submit uservoice bug report if it's not already there.

Comment: actually, the original image could have been suppressed for this reason: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/27021-image-isn-t-displayed-any-more-after-editing-answer

Comment: Steerpike: Can pieces move diagonally, or only hor/vert? Also, presumably if piece2 moves up twice, does that blocks piece1 from going there?

Comment: The ability to move diagonally would be a nice thing to have I must admit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose piece p is at position x, y and can move n squares away to position x2, y2.  This means that the sum of the absolute differences between (x - x2) and (y - y2) can be no greater than n.

If you're going to show which squares can be moved to (rather than taking inputs x2 and y2), I think it'd be best to loop over all positions in a square around the piece.  That is...

```
for (x - n TO x + n):
    for (y - n TO x + n):
        if (abs(x - x2) + abs(y - y2) <= n):
            mark as okay.
```

This answer assumes pieces can only move to adjacent squares and not diagonally.

Edit: If you want diagonal movement, and moving along a diagonal costs just as much as moving horizontally or vertically, then the problem is actually much easier - the piece p can move between the ranges of (x - n, x + n) and (y - n, y + n).

The answer becomes a lot more complex if moving diagonally doesn't cost as much as a horizontal + vertical movement (e.g., if diagonal costs 1.5, whereas h/v costs 1).

Comment: Thank you for the edit to describe diagonal movement as well - very helpful.
It's incredibly impressive and slightly startling to receive such an extra ordinarily clear and practical answer to a problem within 3 minutes of asking the question.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hehe, welcome to StackOverflow. =P This place is *very* fast.

Answer (score 2):

In general such problems involve a reasonably limited grid of places one can possibly reach.  Take a data structure of the size of the grid and whose elements can hold the number of remaining movement points with sufficient precision.

Initialize the grid to a not-visited value.  This must not be in the range of zero to the maximum possible move speed.  A negative value is ideal.

Initialize the starting location to the number of moves remaining.

At this point there are three possible approaches:

1)  Rescan the whole grid each step.  Simple but slower.  Termination is when no points yield a legal move.

2)  Store points on a stack.  Faster than #1 but still not the best.  Termination is when the stack is empty.

3)  Store points in a queue.  This is the best.  Termination is when the queue is empty.

```
Repeat
   ObtainPoint {From queue, stack or brute force}
   For Each Neighbor do
      Remaining = Current - MovementCost
      If Remaining > CurrentValue[Neighbor] then
         CurrentValue[Neighbor] = Remaining
         Push or Queue Neighbor
Until Done
```

Note that with the stack-based approach you will always have some cases where you end up throwing out the old calculations and doing them again.  A queue-based approach will have this happen only if there are cases where going around bad terrain is cheaper than going through it.

Check the termination condition only at the end of the loop, or else terminate when ObtainPoint attempts to use an empty queue or stack.  An empty queue/stack after ObtainPoint does *NOT* mean you're done!

(Note that is is a considerable expansion on Ian's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

This is purely on a conceptual level, but try this logic:

1. Take all possible locations one step away from your starting point and put them on the stack (Moves Taken =0)
2. Pop one off the stack and repeat, using that new coordinate as your new starting point. (Moves Taken=1).  You'll have to ensure that you don't put any duplicate coordinates on the stack
3. Repeat 2 until you've exhausted all your piece's available moves.

I may not be explaining this to well, let me know if you have any questions about what I'm trying to say.

Comment: That does make sense. I think I need to sit down with a pad and pen and just jot through the steps in pseudo code properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the approach above but use recursion instead.

The recursion "depth" is the movement distance.

Break out when depth > movement.

Each iteration should return a vector of spaces and add its own location.

Remove duplicates